# JS Mobile Game Framework supported by Phonegap

Tags: mobile, cordova, javascript-framework

I was interested to know if there is anything as powerful as http://impactjs.com/ but opensource, to ease game development on phonegap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try hits: http://code.google.com/p/playn/

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it currently works well (or at all) with Phonegap, but I have been loving [Crafty](http://craftyjs.com/) for developing HTML5 games on desktop and am planning to start contributing enhancements for mobile to that project.